# How to call an AJAX function after every 15 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have called a JavaScript function on`<body onload>`event where there is a while loop which will iterate unless and until the desired response is fetched from a PHP page.

However since the loop will make a very frequent set of requests, that is causing my browser to hang.

Is there another easy way where we can perform AJAX function request evry 15 minutes without causing much load on the browser?

Answer (score 2):

use setInterval that calls your function every 15 min. something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  // Call to your function that performs an ajax call...
}, 15 * 60 * 1000);
```

Here is link to setInterval documentation:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 2):

You could use a jquery plugin for polling.

https://launchpad.net/jquery.poll

Answer (score 1):

```
var ajax_call = function () {
  $.ajax(options);
};

setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
```

to clear it use

```
clearInterval(ajax_call);
```

Answer (score 0):

Weel i think you can use setTimeout() like this

```
    setTimeout(yourajaxfunction,90000);
// 900000 is the delay in millisecond, after that your function is called.
```

inside your loop so that the function is executed only when the timeout ends.

P.S.

i think ajax was born to be "responsive", you should refresh things responding to an action of the user and not with a timeout in my opinion! :)

Comment: can you suggest some 'responsive' methods then?

Comment: side note..shouldn't it be setTimeout ('yourajaxfunction', 90000) ? the call to the function in quotes? cause i thought you basically should just put some javascript code in those quotes - be it pure code or a script call.

Comment: as for 'responsive' methods, what is it you want to do? keep a table of data up to date and refreshed on update?

Comment: @zladuric - read the doco for setTimeout. The preferred way to use it is to pass it a function reference which is most likely to be either the name of a function defined elsewhere (name *not* in quotes) or an anonymous function defined on the spot. The other way to use it is to pass it a string of javascript to be executed, which in the case of a function call would need brackets 'yourfunction();' - this essentially results in an eval which most people frown upon for various reasons (Google it).

Comment: @zladuric as nnnnn stated using quotes is a bad practice. If you explain better what your needs are i can try to suggest other options (polling seems a good solution to me). Why do you think the user will stay 15 minutes on the same page?What are the use cases?

Comment: @Nicola - this is not my question, so ask the OP. @both Nicola and nnnnnn, thanks for the help. I had to implement something once, which included calling a function and giving it parameters. If I did setTimeout( func(param), 1000) - it didn't work. So I've put it in quotes. That is why I thought it had to be done with the quotes. Btw, what would then be the proper way to pass parameters to the function?